# How to bind component data to two or more properties with different direction?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Let say I have created dropdown it items made up using two textblock with multi-binding and i want to bind one textblock to another string property in my ViewModel ?

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding RID}" Width="0"></TextBlock>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
      </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

For the dropdown item-source is a list with object and object contain field call "RID". What I want to bind "RID" to bind another property.

Comment: Please provide a code example including the relevant parts of both the XAML and the viewmodel. Please edit your question and paste the code *as text, not a screenshot* into your question.

Comment: What property of what object do you want to bind RID to?